# OutOfMemoryException with SQL XML Insert

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net, stream, sqlxml

I have a large XML file (150mb range) on a local disk and using ADO.NET to put it into an nvarchar(max) column. The code looks like this (heavily edited so stuff to leave just the relevant part of the code):

```
using ( var fileStream = new FileStream( myfile , FileMode.Open , FileAccess.Read , FileShare.Read ) )
{
// prep sqlconnection...
sqlCon.Open();
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();      
sqlCommand.Connection = sqlCon;
sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlCommand.CommandText = "[dbo].[bigsproc]";
var param1 = new SqlParameter( "@doc" , SqlDbType.NVarChar , Int32.MaxValue );
param1.Value = new SqlXml( fileStream );
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add( param1 );
var syncResult = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get this problem:

```
ExceptionBody:System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.EncodeChars(Int32 startOffset, Int32 endOffset, Boolean writeAllToStream)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.FlushBuffer()
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.RawText(Char* pSrcBegin, Char* pSrcEnd)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.RawText(String s)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String ns)
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String ns)
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean defattr)
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml.CreateMemoryStreamFromXmlReader(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml..ctor(XmlReader value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetCoercedValue()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.Validate(Int32 index, Boolean isCommandProc)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SetUpRPCParameters(_SqlRPC rpc, Int32 startCount, Boolean inSchema, SqlParameterCollection parameters)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildRPC(Boolean inSchema, SqlParameterCollection parameters, _SqlRPC& rpc)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

What is the best way to get this large disk-based XML into the remote DB server?

Thanks.

Comment: Files are 150mb. The problem is not just one file, but when doing this with multiple .NET Tasks (threads) several can potentially run at the same time, exhausting CLR available memory. Thanks.

Comment: When I save large XML files to the database, I use the binary datatype and compress them first - it is surprising how small the compressed file is vs the uncompressed XML. On retrieval, I simply decompress the XML and deliver it to clients. Can provide a sample if you like? Your alternative is potentially to queue the requests; so you only carry out a couple of saves at a time. Might also be able to stream the Xml across, limiting the amount in memory at one time.

Answer (score 0):

Memory out of exception occurs when the objects are not disposed like if you see the 
SQL connection object is not in the Using statement + SqlCommand class is also IDisposable.

This may not be everytime issue memory overflow crash . But the issue definitely comes when the memory overflows...